# SQL Serverへの接続記述子でANSI_WARNINGSをONにする方法はありますか？

Tags: c#, sql-server

C#でADO.NET経由でSQL Server接続時にANSI_WARNINGSのオプションをONにしたいです。
接続記述子(Connection String)の設定方法でONにするやり方はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SET ANSI_WARNINGS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)によると

> SQL Server Native Client ODBC ドライバー、SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider for SQL Server、および Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server などのクライアントでは、接続フラグで ANSI_WARNINGS が自動的にオンに設定されます。

とのことです。.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Serverについては言及されていませんが、まずは既定でONになっていないか確認されてみてはどうでしょうか？